# Customizing the Grid or x-axis in Android Graph View

Tags: android, graph, android-graphview

I am trying to display 13 labels on the x-axis such as 0,1,2,3,4...12. However, I only get labels in intervals of two 0,2,4,6,8...12.

The labels show up as 0,1,2,3... if I set horizontal labels to 14 but then the labels continue after 13th label and shows half of 14th label even though the maxX of viewport is set to 13.

Is there any method that I can call that will display the vertical grid lines and horizontal labels at intervals of 1?

My code is as follows (The series only has 12 data points with x=1,2,3...12):

```
BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new BarGraphSeries<>(values);
    graph.addSeries(series);


    // Graph properties
    graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph.getViewport().setMinX(0);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxX(13);
    graph.setTitle("Yearly Word Count");
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalAxisTitle("Month");
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalAxisTitle("Word Count");
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(13);
    series.setSpacing(20);
    graph.getViewport().setScrollable(true);
```

The first picture is with NumHorizontalLabels set to 13. The next is set to 14. I want something like the first picture with the grids showing intervals of 1 on the x-axis.

[image: .setNumHorizontalLabels(13)]
[image: .setNumHorizontalLabels(14)]

Comment: are you still facing the issue ? or fixed it ?

Comment: I am not actively working on this right now but no the problem still persisted.

Answer (score 0):

This is your Problem

```
graph.getViewport().setMaxX(13);
```

you are going to display 0...13
Do this instead:

```
graph.getViewport().setMaxX(12);
```

Comment: This would show the labels till 11 and they would still show up in intervals of 2 and not 1 like in the second picture.